# How do I export my python output to GoogleSheets or an Excel Doc? (Sheets Preferred)

Tags: python, excel, google-sheets, output

I'm using the Twint module to get data from Twitter and I need the output to print into a GoogleSheet, how would I go about this?

```
import twint
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

three_days_ago = (datetime.now() - timedelta(3)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

# type keywords you want
keywords = ["Wawa"]

# loop for the keywords
for words in keywords:
    # Configure
    c = twint.Config()
    c.Since = three_days_ago
    c.Search = words
    c.Format = "Tweet id: {id} | Tweet: {tweet} | Username: @{username} | Date: {date} | Time: {time} \n"

    # Run
    twint.run.Search(c)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated your code. According to Twint documentation you can export the output into a .csv file, and after that you can import the .csv into GoogleSheets

```
import twint
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

three_days_ago = (datetime.now() - timedelta(3)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

# type keywords you want
keywords = ["Wawa"]

# loop for the keywords
for words in keywords:
    # Configure
    c = twint.Config()
    c.Since = three_days_ago
    c.Search = words
    c.Format = "Tweet id: {id} | Tweet: {tweet} | Username: @{username} | Date: {date} | Time: {time} \n"

    # add this lines to your script
    c.Store_csv = True
    # here you can filter the needed columns (optional)
    c.Custom_csv = ["id", "user_id", "username", "tweet"]
    # here name your output
    c.Output = "tweets_csv"

    twint.run.Search(c)
```

Comment: Do you think there is a way to have the output print right into a google sheet instead of me having to put the .csv file into a sheet? Appreciate the help!

Comment: According to this thread:
https://github.com/twintproject/twint/issues/132#issuecomment-394349409
you can create a dataframe with twint.Pandas.get() method.
After you got the dataframe you will be able to use this package:
https://pypi.org/project/gspread-pandas/
to import it into GSheets. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use Pandas

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.to_xls(path_to_file_with_name.xlsx)
```

It should save your excel